# CSS Div container show more content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got a div container with content:

```
    <div class="myBtn" tabindex="0">

    Line 1

    Line 2

  </div>
```

And this CSS-Code to change the size

```
div.myBtn:focus {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}

div.myBtn {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Now I want to add that the div shows in the "small mode" only line 1 and
in the bigger mode line 1 and line 2.

I want to add too, that the size of a image in the div changes with the size

Comment: What do you mean by small mode here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding/showing content based on changing height isn't a good idea.

Instead, set the default display of the hidden content to `none` and then modify this to the desired display style on certain conditions.

For example:

```
.line2{
    display: none;
}
.parent:hover .line2{
    display: inline;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="line1">some content</div>
    <div class="line2">some more content</div>
</div>
```